# Better support for parachain-specific questions

Tags: discussion, questions

As the ecosystem is expanding, I am starting to see more parachain-specific questions appear on SE. For example:

- [How to use XCM/P with solidity? Moonbeam => Crust Network Storage Order](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2522/how-to-use-xcm-p-with-solidity-moonbeam-crust-network-storage-order)

How can we foster better support for these types of questions?

Answer (score 7):

1. Make sure these questions are appropriate tagged with the parachain they are asking about.
2. Personally notify these parachain teams to answer these questions.
3. Help these teams set up notifications (using RSS for example), so we don't need to keep notifying them manually.

Teams should be pretty excited that people want to use and are asking about their chain. I suspect, as long as they know the questions exist, they will do the work here.

Answer (score 1):

As Shawn said, I would echo that tagging with the parachain's *name* would be best practice. We should likely also use [tags synonyms](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) to merge all tags under the Polkadot parachain name for all of their other variants when appropriate, like Moonbeam & Moonriver & MOonbase Alpha for example.

I *think* with synonyms in place the RSS will trigger for any such tag (not sure yet of that).

Comment: If it is possible to merge all parachain variant names into one synonym that can be followed, used for tagging along with its variants, then I think this is a great idea.

Comment: Could we create a synonym: `[parachain]` that represents all parachain variants? This could be useful for those who want to follow parachain-specific topics and if you want to ask a question that is relevant to **all** parachains like [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/what-are-the-best-websites-to-use-to-look-for-a-job-in-substrate) one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that we may run into here, by adding tags with the parachain name, is that there is a limit of no more than 5 tags per question:
[image]

I could see use-cases where we want to tag two parachain teams e.g. XCM.

Given the complexity of our stack, perhaps we should consider to increase the limit of our tags to 6.

Comment: that's also an argument for merging tags like `moonbeam` and `moonriver` into a single one.